# PowerShell cmdlet/function not being recognized

Tags: powershell

I'm new to powerscripting and have two powerscritps where runWin1.ps1 calls runWin2.ps1.

`runWin1.ps1` code:

```
cd D:\Powershell_scripts
Start-Process Powershell.exe '.\runWin2.ps1 181 0'
Start-Process Powershell.exe '.\runWin2.ps1 181 22.5'
Start-Process Powershell.exe '.\runWin2.ps1 181 75'
```

`runWin2.ps1` code:

```
#Write-Host 'Case: Wt=', $args[0], 'Gle=', $args[1]
$filePath = "D:\batch_runs\Run" + $args[0] + $args[1]
Set-Location $filePath
Invoke-Expression D:\eps.exe
```

I'm running `runWin1.ps1` from a PowerShell console or cmd window. Everything was working fine with these two pieces of codes and then all of a sudden I started getting this error messages

```
 # : The term ' #' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At D:\Powershell_scripts\runWin2.ps1:1 char:1
+  # W r i t e - H o s t   ' C a s e :   W t = ' ,   $ a r g s [ 0 ] ,   ' ...
+ ~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: ( #:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

  : The term ' ' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At D:\Powershell_scripts\runWin2.ps1:2 char:1
+
+ ~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: ( :String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

 $ : The term ' $' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At D:\Powershell_scripts\runWin2.ps1:3 char:1
+  $ f i l e P a t h   =   " D : \ S e c u r e P r o j e c t s \ D D A M _ X \ D D ...
+ ~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: ( $:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

  : The term ' ' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At D:\Powershell_scripts\runWin2.ps1:4 char:1
+
+ ~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: ( :String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

 S : The term ' S' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At D:\Powershell_scripts\runWin2.ps1:5 char:1
+  S e t - L o c a t i o n   $ f i l e P a t h
+ ~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: ( S:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

  : The term ' ' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At D:\Powershell_scripts\runWin2.ps1:6 char:1
+
+ ~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: ( :String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

 $ : The term ' $' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At D:\Powershell_scripts\runWin2.ps1:7 char:1
+  $ p w d
+ ~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: ( $:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

  : The term ' ' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At D:\Powershell_scripts\runWin2.ps1:8 char:1
+
+ ~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: ( :String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

 I : The term ' I' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At D:\P_powershell_scripts\runWin2.ps1:9 char:1
+  I n v o k e - E x p r e s s i o n   D : \ S e c u r e P r o j e c t s \ D D A M ...
+ ~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: ( I:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

  : The term ' ' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At D:\Powershell_scripts\runWin2.ps1:10 char:1
+
+ ~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: ( :String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Comment: I'm guessing from the spaces between every letter in the error messages that you've changed the encoding of runWin2.ps1, e.g. from ASCII to something 2-byte per character, and powershell.exe is tripping over them.

Comment: Thanks much Tessellating Hacker. I'm still not sure how did the encoding change from ASCII to two bytes per character. May be I was switching between textpad and powershell ISE. Nevertheless thanks so much once again